# I want to display the text in my TextView not as a paragraph but as a few points

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/tvQuestion1"

        android:text=" Q1: What causes relapse?"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textColor="#00695C"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvAnswer1"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:maxLines = "15"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:text="Various “triggers” can put people at risk of relapsing into old patterns of substance use.
         Causes of relapse can differ for each person. 

Some common ones include:

•   negative emotional states (such as anger, sadness, trauma or stress)

•   physical discomfort (such as withdrawal symptoms or physical pain)

•   positive emotional states (wanting to feel even better)

•   testing personal control (“I can have just one pill”)

•   strong temptations or urges (cravings to use)

•   conflict with others (such as an argument with a spouse or partner)

•   social pressures to use (situations where it seems as though everyone else is using drugs)

•   good times with others (such as having fun with friends or family)

"

    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: use \n for new line

Answer (score 1):

Hey for bullet points you can use this :

```
textView1.setText("\u2022" + " " +YOUR TEXT);
```

**\u2022** will give you a bullet point then use **\n** to break the line.
Good luck :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

**String in XML**

```
enter code he<resources>
<string name="app_name">TestProject2</string>

<string name="html">
    <![CDATA[
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <h2>A sub-title</h2>
    <p>This is some html. Look, here\'s an <u>underline</u>.</p>
    <p>Look, this is <em>emphasized.</em> And here\'s some <b>bold</b>.</p>
    <p>This is a UL list:
    <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
    <p>This is an OL list:
    <ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    </ol>
    ]]>
</string>
</resources>re
```

add your data in the string if you need your data show in dot this is the short example it helps you

**xml layout**

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context=".MainActivity"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:gravity="top|fill_vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<!--
<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/helloWorld"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />
-->

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.alvinalexander.testproject2;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get our html content
    String htmlAsString = getString(R.string.html);      // used by WebView
    Spanned htmlAsSpanned = Html.fromHtml(htmlAsString); // used by TextView

    // set the html content on a TextView
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(htmlAsSpanned);

    //        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlAsString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

}

 }
```

this example is look like:

[image]

please try it i think it helps you.